# How can I access the newly built instance inside "fields_for"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a form for nested models by following this http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1.

The example in the link is that `Survey` model has 3 questions. Each `Question` has 4 answers. I copy the example here but remove the `Answer` model to make it simpler.

So the `surveys_controller` has a `new` method that looks like this.

```
# surveys_controller.rb
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  3.times do
    question = @survey.questions.build
  end
end
```

in `views/surveys/_form.html.erb`, we have this:

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <%= render "question_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

and finally this is `views/surveys/_question_fields.html.erb`

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Question" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Question" %>
</p>
```

My question is if I set an attribute of each `question` in the aforementioned `new` method, how can I show that value in views.

Let's say I modify the `surveys_controller.rb` to this:

```
# surveys_controller.rb
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  3.times do
    question = @survey.questions.build
    question.another_attribute = another_value # added line
  end
end
```

How to show the value of `question.another_attribute` inside `<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>` or `_question_fields.html.erb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `:f => builder` into the partial, so you can work with `f`. Calling `f.object` should return the form's object, in this case a question. So the following should work:

```
<%= f.object.another_attribute %>
```